# Disabling BCD testsigning option using registry

Tags: bcdedit

My code should disable testsigning BCD option using Windows registry. The same as command line `bcdedit -set testsigning off`.

I can't do `shellexecute` with cmd. I found one Testsigning reference in registry, in `HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\SystemStartOptions` value, but this value contains current kernel run options, not options for next start.

So, I can't use it.

I found that testsigning option are saved in `HLKM\BCD00000000\Objects\{%GUID%}\Elements\16000049`, but this GUID is different on different PC's.

How I could acquire it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't bother of activating it for all boot entries:

- Enumerate all key names beneath "Objects"
- Write your registry values in a loop into every found key name.

Using NT native API your approach could look something like the following pseudocode:

```
while(numEntries < index){
    NtEnumerateKey(index++, &pGuidKeyname...);
    RtlStringCbPrintfW(buf, %s, rootkey,pGuidKeyname);
    NtSetValueKey(buf, "YES");
}
```